# Momentum matrix elements for two-photon absorption in semiconductors

Tags: semiconductor-physics, perturbation-theory, absorption, matrix-elements

I am trying to follow the paper "Two-photon absorption with exciton effect for degenerate valence bands" (to be found here: https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.9.3502). It gives the momentum matrix elements $<\psi_{ik}\vert\vec{p}\vert\psi_{jk}>$ for the transitions from one band $i$ to another band $j$ for small values of $\vec{k}$. Still, something I do not understand is that the matrix element for the transition between two identical bands (for example from $c\alpha$ to $c\alpha$) is not zero, but rather has the value of $\frac{m}{m_c}\hbar\vec{k}$. Why does the transition from a band to the same band need a matrix element?
Or do I misinterpret the theory behind the matrix elements?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it should not surprise you that this matrix element is not zero - it follows from a direct calculation, and there is no reason why this matrix element should be zero.

Secondly, the discussion applies specifically to two-photon absorption, which is the second order process (in terms of the perturbation theory), i.e. it is proportional to the product of two matrix elements with the intermediate *virtual* state either in the third band or in one of the bands between which the transition occurs. Note that two-photon absorption is only one of many phenomena that involve an *intraband* transition - most of the processes contributing to line broadening are of this nature, although this intraband nature is perhaps less surprizing for phonons or Coulomb scattering, since these often happen at intraband energies.